# ACCESS 2010 Beginner Needs Guidance

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, programming-languages

So, I got a new job where I must write a database system, that is actually very simple. I need to have one full of barcodes, one full of employees, and maybe one more. I'll have no problem making the databases, however I don't know how to write programs to automate it. I need to make a program that automatically inserts barcodes when they are scanned. I also need to make a few queries that will request employee information. I'll need to delete things as well.

I have experience with SQL(PHP MySQL), and a local db program for Android. I'm very familiar with db queries and the like, however I don't know how I write these for ACCESS. Is it built in, or do I use a different language? I assume it's natively written in something like C/C++(which would be one of the more preferable languages to write this in). I don't know Java, C#, or VB. I need to learn this stuff fast, in the next few days. I can't find any good tutorials, the Microsoft one's aren't any good.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you,

Comment: Automatically insert barcodes? Is this appropriate for access? I really don't know.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? A barcode is scanned, and then I write a very simple program that inserts the string into the database.

Comment: You automate Access with Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).  You really shouldn't need to care what Access is natively written in.  Search for pretty much any relevant term with "VBA" as an additional keyword, and you'll find what you need.

Comment: into the access database though? is that common use of access? It seems like you should just use MySQL and not have to go through the frustration of using access

Comment: If you are using an access to develop the application then it's vb.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, basically you need to create an input form in MS Access that will have a text box for the barcode value.  You can get a barcode scanner to just insert it's value into whatever input box has the focus.  You won't have to program any interaction with the barcode scanner as that will be handled by the barcode driver/software.  All you have to do is write an input form that inserts records into the database table.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So how do I write that form? Somebody above said I need to use Visual Basic for Applications? Is this the only way? I hate VB, but will do it if I have to.

Comment: Theres a view as sql option in access, type away, ignore that cookie cutter gui thing.

Comment: Access has a form designer for that, coding is VBA though. You could write something in C++ to use access as a backend. Then when access is dscovered to be unsuitable for the requirement, you can just point your app at a full DBMS. Who picked access and why? It's an excellent ad hoc data analysis tool, writing all but trivial apps is a nightmare though.

Comment: I'm writing the inventory, shipment, etc - systems for a massive raspberry factory, Haha. They use access to store their stuff, but somehow have been doing everything by hand, inputing everything by hand. I couldn't believe it. They insist on using access, if I could just write this in a scripting language or C++ I'd probably be done by now.

Comment: Ooh one more question. Will my DB need to be local or not, the DB will just be in an office within the WAN.

Comment: @Scriptonaut: for the local question, you probably should consider opening another question here on stackoverflow.  Quickly, the answer depends on how it will be used.  Is it going to always be running on one machine operated by one person?  Or will it need to run on multiple machines with users working simultaneously?  If you need multiple users then you will need to look into creating a front-end back-end architecture in access.

Comment: It will be used by multiple users, much like a database for a website. Damn, I will probably post a new question when the time comes.

Comment: Hmm surprised the site didn't filter out your f-bomb.. learn something new everyday. You've got your work cut out for you on this project as, as with many projects, it seems so simple on the surface but the devil is in the details.  Really for each of these question you have you should created a separate stack overflow question.  You don't have to ask one at a time, you can have multiple questions open at the same time.  One question though is you mention multiple databases, are these related in some way?  Or are they totally separate?

Comment: Does your barcode scanner interface like a keyboard?

Comment: Do not use access for a system like this, If they can't afford sql server server of some such, use mysql, or post gre of Anything but a desktop. Unless you are going to hide access behind a service, you won't have client server (it's a shared file on the network !). And to have an Access front end, you have to use the access run time, or deploy access on to every client. If some want to use access to look at the data, fine (a copy of it anyway), but cooker cutter access app for something serious, no, in fact hell no.

Comment: I talked to my employer, he said he wants to use access because it works well with quickbook. I'm not even sure what he's using quickbook for, I think he looks at reports on it or something.

Comment: There's only going to be about 5 clients total. This whole thing seems like a pain in the ass, I would kiss the ground if I could write this thing in mysql. The backend is going to be on a web-server. I feel that this project is going to crash and burn partway through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like your question is how do I create a form in access to insert a record?  There a tons of tutorials on the web for this sort of thing.  It's been a while since I've developed with Access (ugh, but it can be really fast developing) but it looks like things have become even more automated.  I like video tutorials.

Try this one:

[Creating data-entry forms to Access 2010 Essential Training](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qS1qr5tUe0)

(google something like "access 2010 create input form" for more)

Comment: Thank you :)

I'll check it out